# How to store value in a variable on Client click in a Grid View?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to store data in a variable on client click in a grid view.

I have a Stored Procedure which returns Service Id depending on Department code passed and we are binding these details to a Grid View.How do we bind Service Id to a variable which can be used anywhere in the code to pass the same to different Stored Procedure.Currently i am hard coding data for testing purpose.
While binding to grid view,we are not showing Service Id anywhere but we are returning the same in data table.I am doing RowDataBound but unable to store clicked element in variable
.

C# part

```
protected void gvServiceCount_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{   int serviceId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
    Session["serviceId"] = serviceId;
}
```

ASP.NET part

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvServiceCount" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Data Found"
                    Width="100%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#facf5a" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvServiceCount_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="gvServiceCount_RowDataBound"
                    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" RowStyle-BackColor="White"
                    RowStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                    <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Closed">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lblClosedCount" Text='<%#Eval("SUMOFAPPROVEREJECTED") %>' runat="server" OnClick="lblClosedCount_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Data should be stored in a variable on client click.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself (see [mcve]). Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and will most likely not be answered. **For more Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Your `serviceID` session will always be the last value of the GridView. But what do you mean by "not working". Is the serviceID not always the same for each row, or are you getting errors?

Comment: ServiceId not always the same for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Closed">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblClosedCount" Text='<%#Eval("SUMOFAPPROVEREJECTED") %>' runat="server" data-serviceid='<%#Eval("ServiceId")' OnClick="lblClosedCount_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code:

```
protected void lblClosedCount_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string serviceId = lblClosedCount.Attributes["data-serviceid"].toString();
    // your coding here ----
}
```